# SBT plugin causes IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

I have two sbt plugins that I wrote, usinh them individually works but using them both in a project causes sbt build to fail with following exception

```
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.
[error] java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
[error]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[error]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
[error]         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
[error]         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
[error]         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
[error]         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
[error]         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
[error]         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[error]         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
[error]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[error]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
[error]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[error]         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[error]         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.ModuleUtilities$.getObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:20)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.ModuleUtilities$.getCheckedObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:27)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.ModuleUtilities$.$anonfun$getCheckedObjects$1(ModuleUtilities.scala:31)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.$anonfun$map$1(Stream.scala:414)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1167)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1157)
[error]         at scala.collection.generic.Growable.loop$1(Growable.scala:53)
[error]         at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:57)
[error]         at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:49)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:185)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:43)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$plus$plus(TraversableLike.scala:146)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$plus$plus$(TraversableLike.scala:142)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.List.$plus$plus(List.scala:206)
[error]         at sbt.internal.PluginDiscovery$.discoverAll(PluginDiscovery.scala:56)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadPlugins(Load.scala:1318)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadPluginDefinition(Load.scala:1263)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.buildPlugins(Load.scala:1242)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.plugins(Load.scala:1225)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$loadUnit$2(Load.scala:694)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$loadUnit$1(Load.scala:694)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:688)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$builtinLoader$4(Load.scala:484)
[error]         at sbt.internal.BuildLoader$.$anonfun$componentLoader$5(BuildLoader.scala:176)
[error]         at sbt.internal.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:241)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI$1(Load.scala:546)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:562)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:492)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.load(Load.scala:471)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$apply$1(Load.scala:251)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.apply(Load.scala:251)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:69)
[error]         at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:829)
[error]         at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:829)
[error]         at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2(Main.scala:800)
[error]         at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:142)
[error]         at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:137)
[error]         at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:181)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:151)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$2(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]         at sbt.State$$anon$1.runCmd$1(State.scala:246)
[error]         at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:250)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$1(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:132)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:110)
[error]         at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:22)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:104)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:59)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:44)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:35)
[error]         at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:138)
[error]         at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:89)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:111)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:130)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:111)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:37)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:119)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:20)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:56)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:18)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? [error] java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

I created a simple sample project that reproduces the error
https://github.com/austek/sbt-debug-plugin

any ideas what might be causing it or how to go about troubleshooting the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, your example project does not work for me:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: nl.jworks.markdown_to_asciidoc#markdown_to_asciidoc;1.0: not found
[warn]  :: ch.netzwerg#paleo-core;0.11.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

**However**, if your read the original error carefully, you find a

```
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.
```

Ususally, this means that both your plugins have at least one common dependency but in different (incompatible) versions.

I'd recommend to start *sbt* in your projects *project* folder and run `evicted`. This should show you if a dependency in one of your plugins was discarded because of a newer version in the dependencies of your other plugin.

**UPDATE**

**NOTE** Your issue happens when sbt tries to use your loaded plugins. The SBT phase where plugins are loaded is just another SBT project inside your actual project located in the directory ominously named `project`.

When you `cd` into that `project` directory inside your project root and execute `sbt evicted` you will get the following output:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/sascha/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /home/sascha/dev/sbt-debug-plugin/project/project
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/home/sascha/dev/sbt-debug-plugin/project/project/"), "project-build")...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading settings for project project from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to project (in build file:/home/sascha/dev/sbt-debug-plugin/project/)
[info] Updating ...
[warn] Resolving a snapshot version. It's going to be slow unless you use `updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withLatestSnapshots(false)` options.
[info] Out of 1 candidates we found for com.mdsol#sbt-swagger2markup;0.1-SNAPSHOT in sonatype-snapshots, we are choosing sonatype-snapshots.
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/nl/jworks/markdown_to_asciidoc/markdown_to_asciidoc/1.0/markdown_to_asciidoc-1.0.jar ...
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/ch/netzwerg/paleo-core/0.11.0/paleo-core-0.11.0.jar ...
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/pegdown/pegdown/1.4.2/pegdown-1.4.2.jar ...
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.8.1/jsoup-1.8.1.jar ...
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/parboiled/parboiled-java/1.1.6/parboiled-java-1.1.6.jar ...
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/parboiled/parboiled-core/1.1.6/parboiled-core-1.1.6.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] nl.jworks.markdown_to_asciidoc#markdown_to_asciidoc;1.0!markdown_to_asciidoc.jar (240ms)
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.pegdown#pegdown;1.4.2!pegdown.jar (269ms)
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.parboiled#parboiled-java;1.1.6!parboiled-java.jar(bundle) (606ms)
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.parboiled#parboiled-core;1.1.6!parboiled-core.jar(bundle) (713ms)
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] ch.netzwerg#paleo-core;0.11.0!paleo-core.jar (723ms)
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.jsoup#jsoup;1.8.1!jsoup.jar (792ms)
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.
[warn] Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[warn]  * com.github.jnr:jnr-constants:0.9.12 is selected over {0.9.9, 0.9.11}
[warn]      +- com.github.jnr:jnr-enxio:0.19                      (depends on 0.9.11)
[warn]      +- com.github.jnr:jnr-unixsocket:0.20                 (depends on 0.9.11)
[warn]      +- org.jruby:jruby-core:9.2.7.0                       (depends on 0.9.11)
[warn]      +- com.github.jnr:jnr-posix:3.0.49                    (depends on 0.9.9)
[warn]  * com.github.jnr:jnr-enxio:0.19 is selected over 0.18
[warn]      +- org.jruby:jruby-core:9.2.7.0                       (depends on 0.19)
[warn]      +- com.github.jnr:jnr-unixsocket:0.20                 (depends on 0.18)
[warn]  * io.vavr:vavr:0.9.1 is selected over 0.9.0
[warn]      +- io.github.swagger2markup:swagger2markup:1.3.3      (depends on 0.9.1)
[warn]      +- ch.netzwerg:paleo-core:0.11.0                      (depends on 0.9.0)
[warn]  * com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 is selected over 2.0.1
[warn]      +- com.github.fge:btf:1.2                             (depends on 2.0.1)
[warn]      +- com.github.fge:uri-template:0.9                    (depends on 2.0.1)
[warn]      +- com.github.java-json-tools:json-schema-core:1.2.8  (depends on 2.0.1)
[warn]      +- com.github.fge:json-patch:1.6                      (depends on 2.0.1)
[warn]      +- com.github.fge:msg-simple:1.1                      (depends on 2.0.1)
[warn]      +- com.github.java-json-tools:json-schema-validator:2.2.8 (depends on 2.0.1)
[warn]      +- com.github.fge:jackson-coreutils:1.8               (depends on 2.0.1)
[warn]  * com.google.guava:guava:20.0 is selected over 16.0.1
[warn]      +- io.swagger:swagger-core:1.5.19                     (depends on 20.0)
[warn]      +- com.github.fge:uri-template:0.9                    (depends on 16.0.1)
[warn]      +- com.github.fge:jackson-coreutils:1.8               (depends on 16.0.1)
[info] Here are other dependency conflicts that were resolved:
[info]  * joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9 is selected over 2.9.7
[info]      +- org.jruby:jruby-core:9.2.7.0                       (depends on 2.9.9)
[info]      +- com.github.java-json-tools:json-schema-validator:2.2.8 (depends on 2.9.7)
[info]  * com.github.jnr:jnr-posix:3.0.49 is selected over 3.0.46
[info]      +- com.github.jnr:jnr-unixsocket:0.20                 (depends on 3.0.46)
[info]      +- org.jruby:jruby-core:9.2.7.0                       (depends on 3.0.46)
[info]  * commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2 is selected over 1.1.1
[info]      +- org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:2.1      (depends on 1.2)
[info]      +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2         (depends on 1.2)
[info]      +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.2          (depends on 1.1.1)
[info]  * com.github.fge:jackson-coreutils:1.8 is selected over 1.6
[info]      +- com.github.java-json-tools:json-schema-core:1.2.8  (depends on 1.8)
[info]      +- com.github.fge:json-patch:1.6                      (depends on 1.6)
[info]  * com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.5 is selected over 2.2.3
[info]      +- io.swagger:swagger-core:1.5.19                     (depends on 2.9.5)
[info]      +- com.github.fge:jackson-coreutils:1.8               (depends on 2.2.3)
[info]  * com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.5 is selected over 2.9.0
[info]      +- io.swagger:swagger-models:1.5.19                   (depends on 2.9.5)
[info]      +- io.swagger:swagger-core:1.5.19                     (depends on 2.9.5)
[info]      +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.5  (depends on 2.9.0)
[info]  * org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22 is selected over {1.7.18, 1.6.3}
[info]      +- io.swagger:swagger-models:1.5.19                   (depends on 1.7.18)
[info]      +- io.swagger:swagger-core:1.5.19                     (depends on 1.7.18)
[info]      +- io.github.swagger2markup:markup-document-builder:1.1.2 (depends on 1.7.18)
[info]      +- org.slf4j:slf4j-ext:1.6.3                          (depends on 1.7.18)
[info]      +- io.swagger:swagger-parser:1.0.35                   (depends on 1.7.18)
[info]  * commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10 is selected over 1.9
[info]      +- io.github.swagger2markup:markup-document-builder:1.1.2 (depends on 1.10)
[info]      +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2         (depends on 1.9)
[info]  * org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4 is selected over {3.3.2, 3.2.1}
[info]      +- io.github.swagger2markup:markup-document-builder:1.1.2 (depends on 3.4)
[info]      +- io.swagger:swagger-core:1.5.19                     (depends on 3.2.1)
[info]      +- org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:2.1      (depends on 3.3.2)
```

Usually, the lines prefixed with `[WARN]` are the most insightful. The most likely candidates for causing your exceptions are

```
com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 is selected over 2.0.1
com.google.guava:guava:20.0 is selected over 16.0.1
```

due to the major version increments.

The solution would be to either upgrade dependencies in one plugin or downgrade them in the other.

Comment: sorry was missing resolvers, I added them now.  Actually the exception prevents sbt from loading, can't really run anything